# Consuming a particular webservice fails

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I have an issue consuming the webservice, basically i have the following webservice which i would like to consume in my web application, but everytime i try in my solution to add it i get an error.

Here is the link to service: http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertAcceleration.asmx?WSDL
Here is the website of the service: http://www.webservicex.net/WS/WSDetails.aspx?WSID=39&CATID=13

In my solution I click on "Service References" with the right mouse button and choose for "Add Service Reference" I fill in the link and click on "GO".

But I can't add it it just say "The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information."

And it is in VS2008 Framework .NET 3.5

So any idea?

Comment: i m sure , you are adding service reference to this http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertAcceleration.asmx?WSDL and Not this http://www.webservicex.net/WS/WSDetails.aspx?WSID=39&CATID=13

Comment: yes i'm adding: http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertAcceleration.asmx?WSDL

Comment: @Alnedru I have tried adding Service Reference http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertAcceleration.asmx?WSDL & it added successfully.

Comment: Can you give the full error? I suspect somehow that you are copying some invalid characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember in Visual Studio 2008.

You needed to

- click Advanced
- Add Web Reference...
- enter the wsdl
- add reference